Unable to write data into azure datalake storage gen2 file using API query
I am trying to write data into a ADLS gen2 file using curl command by passing it with header parameters and full storage path along with SAS URL. But it is throwing me error :
"error":{"code":"MissingRequiredHeader","message":"An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.\nRequestId:4a00acff-201f-0065-12ba-e7b8ff000000\nTime:2024-08-06T04:38:08.8625985Z"}

My query is as below: -
curl -X PUT \

  -H "x-ms-version: 2020-02-10" \

  -H "x-ms-date: $(date -u)" \

  -H "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob" \

  -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \

  -H "Content-Length: 13" \

  --data "Sangram Mohanty" \

  "https://targetsystem.dfs.core.windows.net/target/sink/write_from_variable.txt?sp=racwmeop&st=yyyy-MM-ddT04:33:40Z&se=yyyy-MM-ddT12:33:40Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

My ultimate purpose is to write data from a variable into a given file using web activity. But in ADF too it is failing with same error. I tried chatgpt but was unable to solve this.
Can anybody please help me which particular header value is missing in my curl command that is forbidding me from writing to it.
My simple purpose is to write small data into a ADLS gen2 file using curl command. That's it.
Thank you

Can you provide your web activity configurations? sample input and expected output?

curl -X PUT 
-H "x-ms-version: 2020-02-10" 
-H "x-ms-date: $(date -u)" 
-H "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob" 
-H "Content-Type: text/plain" 
-H "Content-Length: 13" 
--data "Sangram Mohanty" 
"https://targetsystem.dfs.core.windows.net/target/sink/write_from_variable.txt?sp=racwmeop&st=yyyy-MM-ddT04:33:40Z&se=yyyy-MM-ddT12:33:40Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
A few things to note:
I’ve added the -H "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob" header, which is required for creating a blob (file) in Azure Blob Storage.
Make sure to replace the placeholders (https://targetsystem.dfs.core.windows.net/target/sink/write_from_variable.txt and the SAS token) with your actual ADLS Gen2 URL and SAS token.

"x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob" was already there in my query. But it is not working.

It is still failing. curl -X PUT -H "x-ms-version: 2020-02-10" -H "x-ms-date: $(date -u)" -H "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob" -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -H "Content-Length: 13" --data "Sangram Mohanty" "https://xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/target/sink/write_from_variable.txt?sp=racwmeop&st=2024-08-06Tdd:33:40Z&se=yyyy-MM-ddT12:33:40Z&spr=https&sv=yyyy-MM-02&sr=b&sig=xxxx"
{"error":{"code":"MissingRequiredHeader","message":"An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.\nRequestId:06400baf-701f-0010-30c5-e73f44000000\nTime:2024-08-06T05:56:57.6738147Z"}}

I gave a try again. It is working now. It was issue with my SAS token. You need to give sufficient permission to your SAS token else it will fail. Else code is working fine.
